# Closed subschemes and quasi-coherent sheaves of ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let me quote two results from Qing Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*:

Lemma 2.2.23: Let $X$ be a ringed space, $\mathcal{J}$ be a sheaf of ideals on $X$, $V(\mathcal{J}) = \{x\in X\;:\;\mathcal{J}_x \neq \mathcal{O}_{X,x}\}$, and $j:V(\mathcal{J})\to X$ be the inclusion. Then $V(\mathcal{J})$ is a closed subset of $X$, $(V(\mathcal{J}),j^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}))$ is a ringed space, and $(j,j^\#)$ is a closed immersion where $$j^\#:\mathcal{O}_X\to j_*j^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}) = \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}$$ is the canonical projection.

The very next proposition states the converse, that is a closed immersion $Y\to X$ gives rise to a sheaf of ideals (namely the kernel) whose closed subspace is isomorphic to $Y$. Explicitly,

Proposition 2.2.24: Let $f:Y\to X$ be a closed immersion of ringed spaces, $\mathcal{J}:=\operatorname{ker}f^\#$, and $Z = V(\mathcal{J})$. Then $f$ factors into an isomorphism $Y\simeq Z$ followed by the canonical closed immersion $Z\to X$.

Together, these imply that there is a one-to-one correspondence between sheaves of ideals $\mathcal{J}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$ and closed subschemes $Z$ of $X$ via $\mathcal{J}\mapsto V(\mathcal{J})\mapsto \ker(\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}) = \mathcal{J}$. Am I interpreting this correctly?

I believe this is all good so far. What confuses me is what happens one introduces quasi-coherence.

Proposition 5.1.15: Let $X$ be a scheme, $Z$ be a closed subscheme, and $j:Z\to X$ denote the canonical closed immersion. Then $\operatorname{ker}j^\#$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals on $X$, and the map $Z\mapsto\operatorname{ker}j^\#$ establishes a bijection between closed subschemes of $X$ and quasi-coherent sheaves of modules on $X$.

Here are my two questions:

1. When working over a scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, are all sheaves of ideals of $\mathcal{O}_X$ quasi-coherent?

Proof? If $\mathcal{J}$ is any sheaf of ideals of $\mathcal{O}_X$, then the canonical map $(j,j^\#):(V(\mathcal{J}),j^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J})\to(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a closed immersion, i.e. $(V(\mathcal{J}),j^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J})$ is a closed subscheme of $X$, hence by Proposition 5.1.15, $\ker j^\# = \mathcal{J}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals.

2. Could someone kindly provide an example of a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and a sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{J}$ that is not quasi-coherent?

Assuming 1. is actually correct, it ought to be the case that $X$ cannot be a scheme, right?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to question 1 is no, and the counterexample we produce is also valid for question 2. Let $X=\Bbb A^1_k$, let $U$ be the complement of the origin, and consider $j_!\mathcal{O}_U$, the sheaf which takes the value $\mathcal{O}_U(W)$ for $W$ an open subset contained in $U$ and $0$ else. This is a sheaf of ideals, but it's not quasi-coherent: it has no nonzero global sections, despite not being the zero sheaf.

The correct statement is that there is a one-to-one correspondence between *quasi-coherent* sheaves of ideals on $X$ and closed subschemes of $X$.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening counter-example. Could you point to what is wrong then with my interpretation of 2.2.23 and 2.2.24? It really does seem to me like it establishes this correspondence. Moreover, what is wrong with my "proof"?

Comment: I don't have a copy of Liu's text at hand, but the issue is almost certainly that his definition of a closed immersion is deficient: if $i:Z\to X$ is a closed immersion, the kernel $\mathcal{J}$ of $i^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_Z$ should be locally generated by global sections. What this means is that for any point $x\in X$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ so that $\mathcal{J}|_U$ is globally generated - this fails for my counterexample at $x=0$. Adding this assumption fixes everything, as you can see in the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QN).